# Single Korean word or phrases which expresses '억지로 끼워맞추다'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

When I was grading some students' Korean writing in a class in which I give comments in Korean, I suddenly recognized that I don't know a single word which expresses something like 'putting unmatched things together'.
The question which was given to the students was to write a Korean essay that contains given words. Some students have created a story in which these words are connected closely. However, some students have failed to invent such a story and only listed some sentences which contains those words where they are not so well organized.

I want to express a sentence like 'In this writing, however, the words are used but not in an organized manner....'
What is a proper Korean word which expressed this idea.

'억지로 끼워맞추다'라는 뜻의 한국어 단어가 없을까요?
저는 학생들의 에세이를 채점해서 피드백을 한국어로 달아주는 일을 하다가, '억지로 끼워맞추다' 혹은 '억지로 끼워맞춘'이라는 뜻의 한국어 단어를 모른다는 것을 알게되었습니다.
해당 수업은 몇 개의 단어를 주고 학생들로 하여금 그 단어들을 활용해서 글짓기를 하도록 하는 것인데요, 어떤 학생들은 그 단어들이 유기적으로 활용된 글을 작성하였지만, 어떤 학생들은 그 단어들을 포함한 문장들을 나열하였을 뿐 연결성이 덜이지는 글을 작성해 내었습니다. 그런 학생들에게 '하지만, 이것은 단어들을 사용하기 위하여 억지로 끼워맞춘 글입니다.'라는 코멘트를 하고싶은데요, 적당한 단어가 있을까요?

Comment: I don't think the whole meaning can be expressed using one word only. I can think of 매끄럽지 않다, but I don't think it is proper enough to vividly explain the case. 단 한 단어로라면 온통 의미를 표현할 수 없을 것 같아요. "매끄럽지 않다"가 기억나지만 그다지 적절하지 않고 그 의미를 생생하게 표현할 수 없을 거라고 생각하는데요.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess 부자연스럽다 is one word that has the same meaning. You can say this Korean expression is 부자연스럽다.

From naver online dictionary:

[Search 부자연스럽다](http://dic.naver.com/search.nhn?dicQuery=%EB%B6%80%EC%9E%90%EC%97%B0%EC%8A%A4%EB%9F%BD%EB%8B%A4&x=0&y=0&query=%EB%B6%80%EC%9E%90%EC%97%B0%EC%8A%A4%EB%9F%BD%EB%8B%A4&target=dic&ie=utf8&query_utf=&isOnlyViewEE=)
[부자연스럽다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=17664100)

Answer (score 1):

The word '작위적' may be suitable for the situation. It means '꾸며서 하는 것이 두드러지게 눈에 띄는. 또는 그런 것.' according to Korean standard grand dictionary; http://stdweb2.korean.go.kr/main.jsp